# How do I run a good easygui choicebox function

Tags: python, pygame, easygui

```
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouseX, mouseY=event.pos
            if warsaw_button.collidepoint(mouseX,mouseY):
                choices = ["build a structure", "acquire units", "destroy structure", "launch from silo"]
                choicebox("What do you want to do commander?", warsaw_name, choices)
                if choicebox == choices[0]:
                    msgbox("you want to build a structure")
                elif choicebox == choices[1]:
                    msgbox("you want to acquire more units")
                elif choicebox == choices[2]:
                    msgbox("you want to destroy structures you built")
                elif choicebox == choices[3]:
                    msgbox("you want to launch missile from a silo")
```

When ever I choose something, the msgbox just wouldn't come out

Comment: The *`choicebox` function itself* is never going to be equal to a string.  You need to store the result of *calling* the function in a variable, then test that variable against the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing the `choicebox` function against your strings. Instead, test the **result** of the `choicebox` function against your strings. To make it cleaner, assign it to a `choice` variable.

```
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouseX, mouseY=event.pos
            if warsaw_button.collidepoint(mouseX,mouseY):
                choices = ["build a structure", "acquire units", "destroy structure", "launch from silo"]
                choice = choicebox("What do you want to do commander?", warsaw_name, choices)
                if choice == choices[0]:
                    msgbox("you want to build a structure")
                elif choice == choices[1]:
                    msgbox("you want to acquire more units")
                elif choice == choices[2]:
                    msgbox("you want to destroy structures you built")
                elif choice == choices[3]:
                    msgbox("you want to launch missile from a silo")
```